# Angular: Multiple drop down list

Tags: angular

I created panel where I can change the status of the order. List is displayed correctly but there is one problem, because when I set the value in one list it will set the same value in all the others.How to change it?
[image]

```
     <table id="cart" class="table table-hover"  *ngFor="let order of userOrderList" >
        <thead style="background-color: #F0F8FF">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:20%; text-align: left"><strong>Order id: </strong> {{order.orderId}}</th>
          <th style="width:30%; text-align: left"><strong>Date: </strong>{{order.dateCreated}}</th>
          <select [(ngModel)]="orderSelected" >
              <option  *ngFor='let item of orderState | keys'  [value]="item.key" >{{item.value}}</option>
          </select>
          <th style="width:40%; text-align: right; color: red">Total cost: {{order.totalPrice}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let productOrder of order.OrderIteams" style="border: none">
              <div class="col-sm-4" [routerLink]="['/products-details', productOrder.Product.Id] " ><img src="{{productOrder.Product.Image}}" style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px;padding-top:10px;  padding-right:50px "    class="img-responsive"/></div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
               <strong> {{productOrder.Product.Name}}</strong>
              </div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because each `select` is bound to the same model which is `orderSelected`. As you want an input per item in the loop the easiest thing to do would be to bind it on a property of each item you are iterating over.

Example:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="order.orderSelected">
```

---

#### Full code

```
<table id="cart" class="table table-hover" *ngFor="let order of userOrderList" >
  <thead style="background-color: #F0F8FF">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:20%; text-align: left"><strong>Order id: </strong> {{order.orderId}}</th>
      <th style="width:30%; text-align: left"><strong>Date: </strong>{{order.dateCreated}}</th>
      <select [(ngModel)]="order.orderSelected" >
          <option  *ngFor='let item of orderState | keys'  [value]="item.key" >{{item.value}}</option>
      </select>
      <th style="width:40%; text-align: right; color: red">Total cost: {{order.totalPrice}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let productOrder of order.OrderIteams" style="border: none">
          <div class="col-sm-4" [routerLink]="['/products-details', productOrder.Product.Id] " ><img src="{{productOrder.Product.Image}}" style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px;padding-top:10px;  padding-right:50px "    class="img-responsive"/></div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
           <strong> {{productOrder.Product.Name}}</strong>
          </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Or just create an orderSelectedArray, add `let i = index` at the end of your ngFor and bind your select to `orderSelectedArray[i]`

Comment: @Cyril - also equally valid.